# How can $\text{deg }(f)= \text{d }(f) $ if they're defined differently?

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, definition

From Rotman's **Algebraic Topology**:

> Prove: If $f : S^1 \rightarrow S^1, $ then $\text{deg }f = d(f)$.

But based off of the definitions Rotman provided below, I do not see how this is possible:

> "$\text{deg }$" is defined as:  If $f : (I, \dot I) \rightarrow (S^1,1)$ is continuous with $I = [0,1]$ and $\dot I = \{0,1\}$, define the degree of $f$ by $\text{deg } f = \tilde f(1)$, where $\tilde f$ is the unique lifing of $f$ with $\tilde f(0) = 0$.
>
> "$d$" is defined as:  A continuous map $f : S^n \rightarrow S^n$ (where $n \gt 0$) has degree $m$, denoted $d(f) = m$, if $f_* : H_n(S^n) \rightarrow H_n(S^n)$ is multiplication by $m$.

The proof uses the Hurewics isomorphism $\psi$ and a theorem:

> If $f$ is a closed path in $S^1$ at $1$ and if $m \in \Bbb Z$, then $t \mapsto f(t)^m$ is a closed path in $S^1$ at $1$ and $\text{deg }f = m*\text{deg }(f)$.
>
> ---

But how can this be possible? If we're assuming $f : S^1 \rightarrow S^1$, then $\text{deg }f$ is undefined.

Comment: In the version of the book I found (I assume you are referencing exercise 4.16?), it is not spelled out clearly, but the problem says to define degree in terms of the fundamental group, and so I think the degree of a map $S^1\to S^1$ must be the degree of the image of $1$ under the induced homomorphism on fundamental groups, this image can be interpreted as a homotopy class of paths. Mostly what this boils down to is that the Hurewicz map is natural.

Comment: A map $(I, \dot I) \to (S^1,1)$ is canonically the same as a map $S^1\to S^1$.

Comment: @JustinYoung Can you elaborate?  I don't understand what you mean by the degree of the image of a point.

Comment: @CaptainLama Can you expand on that?  I don't understand how the two maps being canonically the same allows $\text{deg }(f)$ to be defined.

Comment: @PawełCzyż If the theorem is to be changed to $\text{d} (f) = \text{deg } (f')$ with $f'\colon (I, \dot I) \rightarrow (S^1,1)$ by $t \mapsto \text{exp }(2 \pi i t)$, then $\text{deg }(f') = 1$. Then the theorem states $d(f) = 1$.  But we could define $f_*$ such that it is multiplication by $m \neq 1$ and this seems to show that the theorem is false.

Answer (score 1):

I'll clarify what I meant: there is a theorem in the book that the map $\pi_1(S^1, 1)\to \mathbb Z$ given by deg is an isomorphism. So there is a unique homotopy class of paths $i$ so that $deg(i) = 1$, then my claim is that you can define the degree of a (let's say pointed) map $f: S^1 \to S^1$ by looking at $deg(f\circ i)$, this is my best attempt to get what the book means by defining the degree of $f$ "in terms of the fundamental group". If you define degree this way, the naturality of the Hurewicz map yields the result.

Comment: The number $1$ means a few different things in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @JustinYoung observed this is Exercise 4.16 and as @CaptainLama said maps involved are canonically the same.

I will elaborate on this idea in the context of mentioned exercise.

---

We start from a map of pointed spaces $f\colon (S^1, 1)\to (S^1, 1)$.

**Degree via homology**
The map induces a map on homology $f_*\colon H_1(S^1)\to H_1(S^1)$. But $H_1(S^1)=\mathbb Z\langle g\rangle$, so $f_*$ is multiplication by some integer called $\deg_H f\in \mathbb Z$:
$$(\deg_H f) \cdot g = f_*(g).$$

**Degree via fundamental groups**
We have a closed path $h\colon (I,\dot I) \to (S^1, 1)$ given by $h(t)=\exp 2\pi i t$. We define a closed path $f'\colon (I, \dot I)\to (S^1, 1)$ by composition

$$f' := f\circ h$$

We have a covering space $p\colon \mathbb R\to S^1$ where $p(t)=\exp 2\pi i t$. Now we can [lift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Lifting_properties)  path $f'$ to the unique path $\tilde f\colon I\to \mathbb R$ such that $\tilde f(0)=0$. Then we define the degree of $f$ to be
$$ \deg_{FG} f = \tilde f(1) $$
which is necessarily an integer, what comes from the fact that the path $\tilde f$ is closed and $p^{-1}(1)=\mathbb Z$.

**The claim**

> $$\deg_H f = \deg_{FG} f$$

*Proof:* Starting from a map $f$ with $n=\deg_{FG} f$ we homotope it to one of the standard paths
$$a_n\colon (S^1, 1)\to (S^1, 1), \quad a_n(z) = z^n.$$ 
Observe that $f_*=(a_n)_*$, hence 
$$\deg_H f = \deg_H a_n.$$
Moreover using the homotopy from $f$ to $a_n$ you can construct a homotopy from $f'$ to $a_n'$. This implies
$$\deg_{FG} f = \deg_{FG} a_n.$$

Hence it suffices to prove the claim only for "standard" functions $a_n$ which you can do using the Hurewicz theorem.

Comment: Do you mean to say $\text{deg}_{\text{FG}} f' = \tilde f(1)$ instead of $\text{deg}_{\text{FG}} f = \tilde f(1)$?

Comment: I don't understand if you're saying yes or no by that.  If you're defining $\text{deg}_{FG} f = \tilde f(1)$, then it looks like a different theorem because $\text{deg}_{FG}(f)$ looks different than $\text{deg}(f')$, which you said the statement of the theorem should be in the comments above.

Comment: Please, ignore my comments above – in this answer I have reworded everything, I hope this is much clearer now. 

(But $\deg f'$ from the comments above, now deleted, is exactly the same as $\deg_{FG} f$).

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your proof part.  What do you mean by "homotope it to the map $z \mapsto z^n$"?  What is being homotoped and what are the domain and codomain of the function $z \mapsto z^n$?

Comment: The trick here is to deform (by homotopy) an arbitrary path $f'$ to one of the standard paths, for which the theorem is easy.

Comment: I'm not understanding your clarification.  You say "starting from a map $f$" which means $f \colon (S^1,1) \rightarrow (S^1,1)$ since you've defined $n = \text{deg }_{FG} f$, then you say you homotope $f$ to a standard path $a_n$.  But how can there be a homotopy between two maps with different domains?  And I'm not sure what you're referencing when you say "**this** does not change $\text{deg}_H$ as $f$ is determined by the homotopy class of $f$".  What do you mean by "this" and why are you mentioning that it has no change on the functor $\text{deg}_H$?

Comment: You're right, I have used too many shortcuts. I edited the answer. 

Also, you can probably use the Hurewicz isomorphism directly, without mentioning $a_n$ explicitly.

Comment: Why can you say that $f$ is homotopic to $a_n$?  I can see that if $f$ and $a_n$ are homotopic, then $f' = f \circ h$ is homotopic to $a_n' = a_n \circ h$ rel $\dot I$, and then $\text{deg } f' = \text{deg } a_n'$ and $a_n'(t) = \exp(nt) \Rightarrow \text{deg }_{FG}f = \text{deg } a_n' = \text{deg}_{H}f$.  But now I'm not seeing where the Hurewics map fits into this.